# Amazon Cognito authenticate user with saml and get table data from DynamoDB. Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, saml-2.0, amazon-cognito

I am new to Amazon Web Services.

All tables are stored in DynamoDB. My query is how to manage and authenticate user ?

For Example.

Suppose assume I have username called mike and password is testmike. When I press login button using cognito (SAML) they autenticate user and if user return success message then fetch all table data from that user pool. How can we achieve this? I already read amazon developer guide I am confused How to implement in my code.

Or without SAML is this possible ?

Can anybody provide sample code here ?

Your help is really appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own user directory which supports SAML IdP then you can use SAML federation and access your DynamoDB table with Cognito identity credentials.

If you want to create user signup and signin functionality and let Cognito manage your users, you can use Cognito user pools. User data is not stored automatically in DynamoDB. If you want to store some additional data related to user, you can federate Cognito user with Cognito identity and use these credentials to write to Cognito sync or DyanamoDB.

Comment: Yes they support IdP feature. I refer these link. https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx28TCWLHIRK4GT/Announcing-SAML-Support-for-Amazon-Cognito. Client set all necessary permission. and I had access key secret key. But I am new to this feature. How Can I implement step 5 and 6 ? I am really confuse. Can you please provide sample code in swift ? I need sample table data from DynamoDB. How is possible ?

Comment: Which SAML IdP are you using ? Extracting the SAML assertion response is IdP specific.

Comment: Our private sso IdP

Comment: Shibboleth this idp used can you please help me @vinay